# Excel VBA to compare partial rows and delete duplicates

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, duplicates

I need to compare partial data in 2 rows, and clear the data from one row.  I cannot delete any rows entirely. Due to the size of my file, formulas are not preferred (though I have spent hours filtering and deleting in past years).

I have a massive file, 100,000+ rows.  The first 18 columns include identifiers and cannot be deleted.  The next 30-ish columns (variable) contain sporadic data.  Most of the table is blank.

Due to data entry issues, some - but not all - of the data is a duplicate of the previous row.  Using specific columns in the first 18 fields, I can identify which rows may be similar.

I need code to say:
If these 3 (non-sequesntial) columns in row A and row B are the same, then compare the full range of data in Col 19 to Last Col.  Compare A to B and delete the 2nd row. Move to the next pair of rows.

I have working code to delete one cell at a time.  But I can't actually trust the single-cell comparisons - I really need to see if the entire data set for that record is a duplicate of the previous record.  Given this issue, plus the number of blank cells in the data, I believe I need to either create a concatenation of the row data for comparison or use an array.  I cannot find code like this that makes sense for my data set.

```
Sub DeleteCopyData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet

    Dim c As Range

    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim cStart As Range
    Set cStart = Range("A1")

    'Find last row & column.
    lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, cStart.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = ws.Cells(cStart.Row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    With ws
        For i = lRow To 2 Step -1
            'If identifiers in Col 11, 3, and 6 are the same, and the data in Col 24 is the same, clear the duplicate row data.
            If .Cells(i, 11) = .Cells((i - 1), 11) And _
                .Cells(i, 3) = .Cells((i - 1), 3) And _
                .Cells(i, 6) = .Cells((i - 1), 6) And _
                .Cells(i, 24) = .Cells((i - 1), 24) Then     'This needs to be a range or an array of some kind.
                .Cells(i, 24).Clear
            'The 2 lines above this work for one cell, but I need it to compare all data from Col 19 to lCol.
            'If data is the same, clear the duplicate data in row i from Col 19 to lCol.
             End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to be clear... you have vertical columns (A, B, etc.) and horizontal rows (1, 2, etc.) in Excel?  Your paragraph 4 left me a little confused.

Comment: Yes, but the code I'm using is numbering the columns.  S= Col 19, the beginning of my data set.  And Row A and B could be Row 24 & 25 or 30001 and 30002.

Comment: Numbering the columns isn't uncommon; my big hangup was understanding from *If these 3 (non-sequesntial) columns in row A and row B are the same* to the end of that

Comment: Sorry - it is confusing.  If K2=K3 and C2=C3 and F2=F3, compare S2:AB2 to S3:AB3.

Comment: @CeltiaK any reason you can't compare the entire row 2 to entire row 3 and check if they are the same?

Comment: There are differences in the other identifiers.  And I do need to keep each record, even if I delete the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested but this should be close:

Edited - had `Exit Sub` instead of `Exit For`

```
Sub DeleteCopyData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim cStart As Range
    Dim arr, i As Long, n As Long, rowmatch As Boolean

    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
    Set cStart = ws.Range("A1")

    arr = Array(3, 6, 11) 'first set of columns to test for match

    'Find last row & column.
    lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, cStart.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = ws.Cells(cStart.Row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    With ws
        For i = lRow To 2 Step -1

            rowmatch = True

            'perform the initial match on 3 cols...
            For n = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                If .Cells(i, arr(n)) <> .Cells((i - 1), arr(n)) Then
                    rowmatch = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next n

            'got through the first tests - look at the cells starting in col 19
            If rowmatch Then
                For n = 19 To lCol
                    If .Cells(i, n) <> .Cells((i - 1), n) Then
                        rowmatch = False
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next n
            End If

            'no mismatches, so clear from col 19 to end of row
            If rowmatch Then .Range(.Cells(i, 19), .Cells(i, lCol)).ClearContents
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Works great but only clears one row of data.  :-)   I have seen this approach, but don't fully understand it.  I like the simplicity - I'll keep working on getting the additional rows to work.

Comment: Works GREAT!  Thank you so very much.  I've been stuck on this for hours and now I have a new tool.  (The Exit For was the key.)

Comment: Good to hear - sorry about that late edit on Exit Sub.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub DeleteCopyData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lRow As Long, lCol As Long, cStart As Range, C As Range

    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
    Set cStart = ws.Range("A1")

    'Find last row & column.
    lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, cStart.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = ws.Cells(cStart.Row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    With ws
        For i = lRow To 2 Step -1
            'If identifiers in Col 11, 3, and 6 are the same, and the data in Col 19:28 is the same, clear the duplicate row data.
            If .Cells(i, 11) = .Cells((i-1), 11) And _
                .Cells(i, 3) = .Cells((i - 1), 3) And _
                .Cells(i, 6) = .Cells((i - 1), 6) And _
                Join(Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(i, 19), .Cells(i, lCol))), Chr(0)) = _
                Join(Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(i-1, 19), .Cells(i-1, lCol))), Chr(0)) Then
                .Range(.Cells(i, 19), .Cells(i, 28)).Clear
             End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```